# How to initially activate any Web Story in amp-story-player

Tags: amp-html, amp-story

Suppose I have 3 Web Stories to embed in a web page and I want multiple Web Stories in a single viewer.
I will use

```
<amp-story-player style="width: 360px; height: 600px;">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/story1.html" style="--story-player-poster: url('https://www.example.com/assets/cover1.html');">
        Story 1.
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/story2.html" style="--story-player-poster: url('https://www.example.com/assets/cover2.html');">
        Story 2 **Want to activate this story initially**
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/story3.html" style="--story-player-poster: url('https://www.example.com/assets/cover3.html');">
        Story 3
    </a>
</amp-story-player>
```

but initially this activates Story 1 when amp-story-player renders on page.

So, **Is there any way to initially activate Story 2?**

User will swipe to left/right if want to see Story 1/Story 3

Thanks